# Find URLs in HTML-Sourcecode which are not yet tagged. Ignore tagged URLs

Tags: html, regex, tags, grep, pcre

I'd like to find URLs in HTML Sourcecode.
But only URL which don't have Tags around them.
I came up with this:

```
(?<!")((http(s)?://|http(s)?://www\.|(?<!/)www\.)([\w\._\-/&%]+))(?!</a>)
```

It does a good job avoiding URL which are part of links but also finds tagged URLs... 
I thought by testing "not followed by a closing a-tag" I could avoid tagged URLs... 
Where is the mistake

```
<a href="https://foo.com">https://www.foo.com</a> <- should not hit
<span class="bar>www.test.de</span> <-HIT
"http://www.test.de" <- HIT
<a href="http://test.de">http://www.foo.com/_manno/Propello&%_-/ramblay</a> should not HIT
<span>http://www.test.de/alala </span> <-HIT
```

[My RegEx on Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/qeRGdkgYWPGX0QNO)

Comment: The closing `</a>` tag has a forward slash. Not a back-slash. Don't forget there can be spaces.

Comment: I don't understand your condition. Why `"http://www.test.de"` doesn't hit and that `URL` inside `<span>` does hit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make Your sample work - just replace the lookahead (at the end of Your regexp) with:

```
(?![^<]*<\/a>)
```

**P.S.**

If I'd be having similar goal - I'd want following constructions to HIT:

```
<span class="bar>"http://www.my.test"</span> <- I'd want this to HIT ;)
"http://www.test.de" <- I'd want this to HIT too (while not inside a tag)
<a href="http://www.test.de" option="2"> <- should NOT hit
```

If Your goal matches what I just described - then remove the lookbehind completely and replace the respective lookahead with:

```
(?![^<>]*(>|<\/a>))
```

which basically means that URL won't be followed by anything similar to "</a>" or ">" (a closing-bracket of the tag)

Comment: Our goals match! Thanks alot!